Stripe - Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer but it throws 400 Status
for the Webhook i always receive this Status Code from Stripe
Webhook Error: Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) instance representing the raw request body.Payload was provided as a parsed JavaScript object instead.
Signature verification is impossible without access to the original signed material.
Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
I looked into it over a day now and cant figure out where the mistake is in my Code.
Here is the Code:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp();

// Initialize Firestore
const db = admin.firestore();

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to capture raw body for Stripe webhook
app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));

// Stripe webhook endpoint
app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  const eps = functions.config().stripe.webhook_secret;
  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature, eps);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️Webhook signature verification failed:", err.message);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed": {
      const session = event.data.object;
      const userUid = session.client_reference_id;

      console.log("Checkout session completed:", session);

      if (session.payment_status === "paid") {
        try {
          await db.doc(`restaurant/${userUid}/branch/payment`).set(
              {
                paid: true,
              },
              {merge: true},
          );

          console.log(
              `Firestore updated for ${userUid} with payment information`,
          );
          return res.json({received: true});
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error updating Firestore:", error);
          return res.status(500).send(`Update Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Payment status is not \"paid\".");
        return res.status(400).send("Payment status is not paid.");
      }
    }
    default: {
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
      return res.status(400).send(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }
  }
});

// Use express.json() for other routes if needed
app.use(express.json());

// Export the Express app as an HTTP function
exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(app);


I cant figure out what is wrong i hope for the final help here :)
The Status Code to return 200 instead of 400

This is likely due to app.use(express.json()) in your code that parses the request into JSON. Could you remove the line and check if it works?
